# Google speech to text API using C#

Tags: c#, json.net, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api

I'm using google speech recognition for speech to text of a audio file. Response  i get as output shows only {"result":[]}. I don't see any output result.
i have picked my code from [How to use google speech recognition api in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148373/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-c) and [Google speech to text API in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24049507/google-speech-to-text-api-in-c-sharp) . i have tried almost every answer in above links still i am getting the error.

My code is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace google_api
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {

            FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("good-morning-google.flac");
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            memoryStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
            fileStream.Read(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            byte[] BA_AudioFile = memoryStream.GetBuffer();
            HttpWebRequest _HWR_SpeechToText = null; 
            _HWR_SpeechToText =
                        (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
                            "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key=mykey");
            _HWR_SpeechToText.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            _HWR_SpeechToText.Method = "POST";
            _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=44100";
            _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentLength = BA_AudioFile.Length;
            Stream stream = _HWR_SpeechToText.GetRequestStream();
            stream.Write(BA_AudioFile, 0, BA_AudioFile.Length);
            stream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse HWR_Response = (HttpWebResponse)_HWR_SpeechToText.GetResponse();
            if (HWR_Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                StreamReader SR_Response = new StreamReader(HWR_Response.GetResponseStream());                           
                Console.WriteLine(SR_Response.ReadToEnd()+SR_Response.ToString());

                string responseFromServer = (SR_Response.ReadToEnd());
                String[] jsons = responseFromServer.Split('\n');
                String text = "";
                foreach (String j in jsons)
                {
                    dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(j);
                    if (jsonObject == null || jsonObject.result.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    text = jsonObject.result[0].alternative[0].transcript;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE : "+text);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did you print and check the `responseFromServer`?

Comment: yes i tried to print it using Console.WriteLine(SR_Response.ReadToEnd()+SR_Response.ToString()); the output it show is {"result":[]} and  API is responding i checked it on dashboard of google API Manager it shows my activity.

Comment: the response Json obj has two lines. and the second line has the audio-text to print that, we need to parse it. i tried that too it printed nothing

Comment: i think the buffer is not loading the .flac file to the google API else what other can be reason that the json response file is empty

Comment: I believe your audio file should be downloaded in https://github.com/gillesdemey/google-speech-v2.  According to this post [Google Speech Api get text from ...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35172592/google-speech-api-get-text-from-audio-file-returning-result-in-c-sharp), the audio file may have formatting issue, however, I cannot install anything to test the `FLAC` file, so you may need to work on your own.

Comment: that's it, finally speech has been recognized thanks for help Alex