# Parsing multiple objects using Jobject in Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, google-speech-api

I am trying to parse the result from the google speech to text API. The json response is :

```
{"result":[]}
{"result":[
          {"alternative":[
                         {"transcript":"hello Google how are you     feeling","confidence":0.96274596},
                         {"transcript":"hello Google how are you today","confidence":0.97388196},
                         {"transcript":"hello Google how are you picking","confidence":0.97388196},
                         {"transcript":"hello Google how are you kidding","confidence":0.97388196}
                         ]
         ,"final":true}]
,"result_index":0
}
```

Now i am trying to parse it through JObject. The problem is occurring in parsing the Result object which is appearing twice so, how do i parse the second Result object. Here is my code which i am trying is :

```
              StreamReader SR_Response = new StreamReader(HWR_Response.GetResponseStream());
              Console.WriteLine(SR_Response.ReadToEnd()+SR_Response.ToString());
              String json_response = SR_Response.ReadToEnd() + SR_Response.ToString();
              JObject joo = JObject.Parse(json_response);
              JArray ja = (JArray)joo["result"];

                        foreach (JObject o in ja)
                        {
                            JArray ja2 = (JArray)o["alternative"];
                            foreach (JObject h in ja2)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(h["transcript"]);
                            }
                        }
```

Next solution i tried using deserialize object code is:

```
                string responseFromServer = (SR_Response.ReadToEnd());
                String[] jsons = responseFromServer.Split('\n');
                String text = "";
                foreach (String j in jsons)
                {
                    dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(j);
                    if (jsonObject == null || jsonObject.result.Count <= 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine((string)jsonObject["result"]["alternative"][0]["transcript"]);
                    text = jsonObject.result[0].alternative[0].transcript;
                }
                Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE : "+text);
```

Comment: This resopnse is for one api call? two times response?

Comment: What's this, `String json_response = SR_Response.ReadToEnd() + SR_Response.ToString();` Also, your second code operates in a loop it seems split on new lines. Show us an exact example of the Json you are deserializing, and the actual full code along with the output you are receiving.

Comment: You read the stream once with your call to `Console.WriteLine()`: `Console.WriteLine(SR_Response.ReadToEnd()+SR_Response.ToString());`.  Then you immediately try to read it again: `String json_response = SR_Response.ReadToEnd() + SR_Response.ToString();`.  This cannot work, you need to read the stream only once.

Comment: Assuming you fix your stream reading, this looks to be a duplicate of [Parsing large json file in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32237819/3744182) or [Line delimited json serializing and de-serializing](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29729063/3744182).  The trick is to set [`JsonTextReader.SupportMultipleContent = true`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm)

Comment: @ColinM SR_Response.ReadToEnd() is just to read the response from json object in string format & here is my complete code [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40350447/google-speech-to-text-api-using-c-sharp)

Comment: I have to parse the text inside the transcript **hello Google how are you feeling** thus their is no output currently but  `Console.WriteLine(SR_Response.ReadToEnd()+SR_Response.ToStri‌​ng());` print the json response it written on the top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a series of JSON root objects concatenated together into a single stream.  As explained in [Read Multiple Fragments With JsonReader](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ReadMultipleContentWithJsonReader.htm) such a stream can be deserialized by setting [`JsonReader.SupportMultipleContent = true`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReader_SupportMultipleContent.htm).  Thus, to deserialize your stream, you should first introduce the following extension methods:

```
public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeObjects<T>(Stream stream, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        var reader = new StreamReader(stream); // Caller should dispose
        return DeserializeObjects<T>(reader, settings);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<T> DeserializeObjects<T>(TextReader textReader, JsonSerializerSettings settings = null)
    {
        var ser = JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings);
        var reader = new JsonTextReader(textReader); // Caller should dispose

        reader.SupportMultipleContent = true;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.None || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Undefined || reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Comment)
                continue;
            yield return ser.Deserialize<T>(reader);
        }
    }
}
```

Next, using a code-generation utility such as http://json2csharp.com/, generate c# classes for a single JSON root object, like so:

```
public class Alternative
{
    public string transcript { get; set; }
    public double confidence { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public List<Alternative> alternative { get; set; }
    public bool final { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> result { get; set; }
    public int result_index { get; set; }
}
```

And deserialize as follows:

```
List<RootObject> results;
using (var stream = HWR_Response.GetResonseStream())
{
    results = JsonExtensions.DeserializeObjects<RootObject>(stream).ToList();
}
```

Having done this you can use standard c# programming techniques such as [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) to enumerate the `transcript` values, such as:

```
var transcripts = results
    .SelectMany(r => r.result)
    .SelectMany(r => r.alternative)
    .Select(a => a.transcript)
    .ToList();
```

If you don't want define a fixed data model for your JSON collection, you can deserialize directly to a list of `JObject` like so:

```
List<JObject> objs;
using (var stream = HWR_Response.GetResonseStream())
{
    objs = JsonExtensions.DeserializeObjects<JObject>(stream).ToList();
}
```

Then you can use [`SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectToken.htm) to select the values of all the `"transcript"` properties nested inside each object:

```
var transcripts = objs
    // The following uses the JSONPath recursive descent operator ".." to pick out all properties named "transcript".
    .SelectMany(o => o.SelectTokens("..transcript")) 
    .Select(t => t.ToString())
    .ToList();
```

Updated sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/41c3XP) showing both options.

Comment: Please provide any text/value fetch code from **transcript** in reference to the deserialize approach you mentioned so that i can get only the string inside transcript such as _hello Google how are you feeling_